# What is the soundtrack playing in One Piece when god Usopp is held up by the giant?

Tags: one-piece, music

I've been searching since I first heard it before the time-skip.
I believe it was also played before the news coo delivers the paper
to chopper in bird island.
I quit searching and now heard it again in the last chapter. So I'd like to know what soundtrack is being played.

Answer (score 6):

The theme is [Fuyu ni Saku, Kiseki no Sakura](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK_h97JHK-g). It is played when the giant picked up god Usopp.

Comment: thank you a million times :D
thank you thank you thnak you

Comment: no problem bro im here to help :)